# sql group by is duplicating values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with speaker, session, conference, email. my goal is to make a query that combines the conference and session into one field so that we can apply some HTML to it and format it when we preview it elsewhere. 
The issue here is when a speaker is attending two difference conferences and presenting different sessions. This query somehow duplicates the sessions from one conference and applies it to the second conference:

```
SELECT speaker AS 'speakername', email AS 'email',
CAST(
  (SELECT conference AS 'strong',
      (SELECT session AS 'session' from speakersessions AS ds
      WHERE ds.speaker = dd.speaker
      GROUP BY session
      for xml path(''), type) AS 'sessions'
  FROM speakersessions AS ds
  WHERE ds.speaker = dd.speaker
  GROUP BY conference 
  for xml path(''), type)
AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
AS 'conferences'
FROM speakersessions AS dd
GROUP BY speaker, email
```

the results that show for speaker 'greg' are:

```
<strong>Business Planning </strong>
<sessions><session>
10 tips to fast-track
</session><session>
Hybrid planning
</session><session>
Planning on the cloud
</session><session>
The Boardroom
</session></sessions>
<strong>Reporting Analytics</strong>
<sessions><session>
10 tips to fast-track
</session><session>
Hybrid planning
</session><session>
Planning on the cloud
</session><session>
The Boardroom
</session></sessions> <br/>
```

(I added line breaks)
but as you can see, this is not what the speakersessions table shows:

```
Conference                   Session
Business Planning   |   10 tips to fast-track
Business Planning   |   Hybrid planning
Reporting Analytics |   Planning on the cloud
Reporting Analytics |   The Boardroom
```

so the sessions for reporting analytics are not populating. What's going on here?

Comment: Seems like your join `WHERE ds.speaker = dd.speaker` is insufficient then. Perhaps also join on conference in that correlated subquery?

Comment: @JNevill I tried that but it gives me an error "Column 'speakersessions.Conference' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." I tried putting it in both WHERE clauses: `WHERE ds.speaker = dd.speaker and ds.conference = dd.conference`

Comment: You just need it in the inner WHERE clause. Add `conference` to that correlated subquery's GROUP BY as well.

Comment: @JNevill this is the inner part: `(SELECT conference AS 'strong',
 (SELECT session AS 'session' from speakersessions AS ds 
 WHERE ds.speaker = dd.speaker and ds.conference = dd.conference
 GROUP BY session, conference
 for xml path(''), type) AS 'sessions'
FROM speakersessions AS ds
WHERE ds.speaker = dd.speaker 
GROUP BY conference 
for xml path(''), type)
AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
 AS 'conferences'` which gives me the same error I mentioned earlier. The only way I found it works is by doing `GROUP BY speaker, email, conference` in the last line. but i don't want toseparate theconferences

Comment: @JNevill if i do `GROUP BY speaker, email, conference` at the end then it will separate each speaker by conference, which  I don't want to do. I want to have all of a speakers conferences and sessions combined into one field.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT speaker AS 'speakername', email,
 CAST(
    (SELECT conference AS 'strong',
            (SELECT session AS 'session' 
                from speakersessions AS part3
                WHERE part3.conference = part2.conference and part3.email = part1.email
                GROUP BY session,conference
        for xml path(''), type) AS 'sessions'
    FROM speakersessions AS part2
    WHERE part1.email = part2.email 
    GROUP BY part2.conference 
    for xml path(''), type)
 AS NVARCHAR(MAX))  AS 'conferences'
FROM speakersessions AS part1
GROUP BY email, speaker`

 had to make sure that conference was added but that it was joined with the proper subquery